# Vue How to seperate forloop button table into different row in table

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, button, html-table

With the for loop in my first table row, it creates 5 buttons with different values. I would like to know how can I separate those buttons, like making the second button appears in the second `<tr>` to replace button2. And next one to appear in third `<tr>` to replace button3.

If the button is separate, do I need to rewrite @click in ever button? Thank you.

```
          <tr>
            <td>
            <button
              :key="trend.Trends"
              v-for="trend in topThreeTrends"
              @click="LoadTrend(trend.Trends, trend.DT)"
            >{{trend.Trends}}</button>
            </td>
          </tr>


          <tr>
            <td>
              <button @click="currentBreed = 2">button2</button>
            </td>
          </tr>


          <tr>
            <td>
              <button @click="currentBreed = 3">button3</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
```

I don't want to use for loop at `<tr>` like this, which will make me can't customize on each table row, because I have other specific data for each row.

```
<tr
    :key="trend.Trends"
    v-for="trend in topThreeTrends">
  <td>
      <button @click="LoadTrend(trend.Trends, trend.DT)">{{trend.Trends}}</button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `v-for` on the `tr` if that is the element you want to repeat:

```
<tr
    :key="trend.Trends"
    v-for="trend in topThreeTrends">
  <td>
      <button @click="LoadTrend(trend.Trends, trend.DT)">{{trend.Trends}}</button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: So, by this way, I can't modify on specific row right, cause it gotta be all the same?

Comment: You can use `v-if` with a condition for whichever row's button you need to modify